# Why is a Github page url changing on load, causing the public resource path to be incorrect?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, deployment, github-pages

I have a React page made with create-react-app and I deployed it to github pages per the instructions [here](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages). It opens, but the resources on the public directory aren't being loaded. What seems to be happening is that during the page load, ***http://{name}.github.io/{repo}*** is being truncated to ***http://{name}.github.io***, and so the relative path to the public directory is no longer correct at the point when the page attempts to load them. If I try to then reload the page with the url ***http://{name}.github.io*** I get a 404 error.

I could just alter the paths to make it work, but that feels like a hack. I want to know what's going on here and how I might fix it, if that's possible.

The code can be seen here: https://github.com/CBreakr/ATTCK_StarWars

Supplement to the answer: https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1

Comment: for reference, this is the page: http://CBreakr.github.io/ATTCK_StarWars

Comment: You're referencing images (resources as you say) incorrectly. For instance in css you have `url('/images/space.jpg')` but that should be `url('./images/space.jpg')` then in jsx you use plain strings for `src` instead of `import img from 'img.jpg'` more details in docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Comment: Downvoting as question is misleading, there is no proof for changing GitHub url. What the OP is actually asking is why bundled React app does not have correct paths to image resources.

Comment: @Aivaras - if I include the . for the path, then npm run deploy fails with the  error that it can't resolve the path... If I run the application locally there are no issues, if I deploy it as is to Heroku there are no issues

Comment: @Aivaras - Since I first posted this I updated the BrowserRouter to use the basename property, and that stopped the URL switching that was occuring and also let the application fetch the config.json file on load, but the images and fonts still wont load

Comment: It might be better for you to add [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise you're asking people to debug your whole application. Another thing is that you might reproduce it locally by building the app to be served from subfolder (`localhost:3000/myapp`)

Comment: Docs for building the app to be served from a `/path` https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

Comment: I found the attached article, and it seems that the way to do it is to just update all paths used in the app. I had been hoping for some way of avoiding having to do this and having the paths work automatically as part of the github deployment process. https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to say without seeing your code.
However it's likely that your `react-router` is not setup properly.

You should setup your router like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from ‘react-router-dom’;

const routerBaseName = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

ReactDOM.render(<Router basename={routerBaseName}>< App /></Router>, document.getElementById(‘root’));
```

Note the `basename` part - it should be set to your production url when you build the bundle (in this case: `https://CBreakr.github.io/ATTCK_StarWars/`)

it should be set to your localhost url when you are developing locally.

You can use `.env` files to set values for `PUBLIC_URL` (I believe with create-react-app you will have to change it to `REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL`) for dev/prod environments respectively, see: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: I ended up putting it up on Heroku exactly as is and it worked perfectly, so I'm curious why it would have to be set up differently for github.

Comment: Hi @notnot - I checked your code, yes you are missing the `basename` configuration in your `BrowserRouter`. github pages host your site under a path: `{username}.github.io/{reponame}/` when visited, your app will think you are on `{username}.github.io` and `/{reponame}` is a path inside your app - and in your code you are trying to redirect the user to root path `/` for unmatched routes.

Comment: the `basename` prop tells your app what is the real `baseURL` for your app. In this case you should set it to `https://CBreakr.github.io/ATTCK_StarWars/` when you are pushing it to github pages. (you don't need this in `dev` though, that's why i suggested using a .env file to manage it.

Comment: Why would this be necessary for the github page deployment but not for Heroku?

Comment: So I just hardcoded the basename to test it. If I use the full path then the URL changes into "https://cbreakr.github.io/https://CBreakr.github.io/ATTCK_StarWars/" after loading and nothing is fixed. If I instead just set the basename to be the relative path "/ATTCK_StarWars/" then the url is correct and it partially loads correcty, but is still trying to reference images in the wrong place, as if nothing past the first slash is there.

Comment: I added a new branch named "github_page" which shows this new version of the code.

Comment: On page load, it makes a fetch request to a config file. With the basename set to the relative path, the config file is now loaded correctly. However, the components which get constructed based on the config file reference image, and those don't render correctly. In addition, the custom font referenced from the css doesn't load correctly, either.

Comment: Heroku serves your site at root `/` but github serves your site under the name of your repo. the basename should NOT have trailing slash. try `/ATTK_StarWars` instead.

Comment: Removing the trailing slash didn't change anything

Comment: I found the attached article, and it seems that the way to do it is to just update all paths used in the app. I had been hoping for some way of avoiding having to do this and having the paths work automatically as part of the github deployment process. https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1

Comment: Your answer about the basename helped get rid of the most confusing part of the problem, which was the URL switching, so I think that's worth the bounty. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need the homepage defined in package.json

"homepage": "http://gitname.github.io/react-gh-pages"

https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages#procedure

Comment: I've got that set. I followed all of the instructions in that link.

Answer (score 0):

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths. Setting your homepage this way may help `"homepage": "."`.

Also there is another tutorial in the same page you may want to check that as well https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom

Answer (score 0):

The only concerning difference I found, in your [codebase](https://github.com/CBreakr/ATTCK_StarWars) - is the homepage in package.json is not HTTPS.

Current settings -

> "homepage": "http://CBreakr.github.io/ATTCK_StarWars",

Change to -

> "homepage": "https://CBreakr.github.io/ATTCK_StarWars",

It's good that your repo has a `gh-pages` branch that contains your build directory contents. Please make sure the repository deployment settings use `gh-pages` branch.

**EDIT** -
**UPDATED ANSWER**

The URL attribute is wrongly configured for your `<img>` tags. The possible values for the attribute are:

1. Absolute image path - `src="http://www.example.com/image.gif"`
2. Relative image path - `src="image.gif"`

> Note: If you notice that character images are not loading but the movie posters for a character are loading fine, the reason being - the posters have absolute image path e.g. Revenge of the Sith has image source as -
>    `https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/e/e7/EPIII_RotS_poster.png/`)

But character images are configured like `src='/images/vader.jpg'`.

You could solve this by changing src of your static images in `characters.json` from -

```js
"imageURL": "/images/vader.jpg"
```

to:

```js
"imageURL": "images/vader.jpg"
```

OR

```js
"imageURL": "./images/vader.jpg"
```

> You can check the validity of this solution by inspecting the image of your Vader character component [here](https://cbreakr.github.io/ATTCK_StarWars/#/films/4). Update the image tag source and see that the character images now load properly.

Comment: this unfortunately didn't lead to any change

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your Switch Component inside HashRouter like this

```
import { HashRouter} from "react-router-dom";
<HashRouter basename="/">
     <Switch>
           //...        
     </Switch>

 </HashRouter>
```